# Sparkling Water - run python script as a Spark Application

Tags: python, pyspark, h2o, sparkling-water

I have some trouble with Sparkling Water to run a python script as a Spark Application. I use this command to execute my script on Spark :

> ./bin/spark-submit \
>
> --packages ai.h2o:sparkling-water-core_2.10:1.5.12 \
>
> --py-files $SPARKLING_HOME/py/dist/pySparkling-1.5.12-py2.7.egg  $SPARKLING_HOME/Python/test.py

and I have this falling error :

> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: Trying to call a package.

logs :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/sparkling-water-1.5.12/Python/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    hc= H2OContext(sc).start()
  File "/Users/Documents/sparkling-water-1.5.12/py/dist/pySparkling-1.5.12-py2.7.egg/pysparkling/context.py", line 72, in __init__
  File "/Users/Documents/sparkling-water-1.5.12/py/dist/pySparkling-1.5.12-py2.7.egg/pysparkling/context.py", line 96, in _do_init
  File "/Users/Documents/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 726, in __getattr__
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: Trying to call a package.
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.181.84:4042
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/04/11 16:58:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/fold
```

How can I resolve this issue ? I am following exactly the command from the booklet : https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turan/3/docs-website/h2o-docs/booklets/SparklingWaterVignette.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a critical bug we know about in Sparkling Water team and it's fixed in a new release with other hotfixes. The bug is already fixed ( https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/SW-107) and a new release should be out very soon.

I'll keep you updated and let you know when new release is out.

**EDITED 29 April 2016**

New release with the fix is out.

For spark 1.6 - http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/sparkling-water/rel-1.6/3/index.html

For spark 1.5 - http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/sparkling-water/rel-1.5/14/index.html

You don't need to call `-packages` any more to add sparkling-water-core. The pySparkling egg file already contains all necessary Java/Scala classes it needs. So all you need to do is just set egg file using the py-files option and that should be it.